# Image Detector with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection, object-detection-api

I want to build a simple image detector for custom Binary shapes on images.
I may train and use the models on object detection zoo such as ssd_inception_v2 and so on. But it's would be extremely un efficient as it has sizes in hundreds of Megabytes.
and I can't even imagine to use that in my simple app. can anybody suggest me how to solve this?

I have already built excellent small size classifiers for my images. but can't build small scale efficient detector. (their position with detection boxes)

Comment: what do you mean by custom binary shapes? and what do you mean by "can't detect them in images" ?

Comment: See the mnist example in tensorflow or keras.

Comment: @TheEngineer by "custom binary shapes" i meant geometrically simpler binary shapes. for example a circle, half circle and so on.

they can be simply detected by training a normal object detector that's trained on one of those models at the detection models zoo. but i just can't be ok with >100 MB size model for simple application.

Comment: @Cristi I have done a lot of image classification including the mnist sets. But when it comes to detection, it seems harder to efficiently detect the position and size of the image. I had tried to use "moving window" methods and such, but It is unefficient and unacceptable since there already are efficient algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is transfer learning. I would take one of the lightweight models such as [MobileNetV2](https://medium.com/@luis_gonzales/a-look-at-mobilenetv2-inverted-residuals-and-linear-bottlenecks-d49f85c12423) and retrain on my dataset. It should be pretty quick.If you want to even decrease your model size further, feel free to only take the first few layers of the CNN and retrain it. It would be a bit more work since you need to re-write the part of  network you want to use and load it with the pre-trained weights.